# iOS Accessibility fail to focus next tableviewcell

Tags: ios, tableview

I have tableview with these tableview cells: 
- cell have some collectionview and cell have Height larger than haft of screen 
- cell have other tableview inside it

When access to the last item inside cell (collection cell or tableview cell inside), i swipe right to focus on next cell. But it not jump to next cell in tableview, It jump to other item on screen

Example:  i have main tableview, in this table have some cell is expanded cell which have other small tableview inside it. When this cell was expanded and i swipe right to last item of small tableview, then i swipe right again to move to next cell of main tableview view. But this time the next cell of main tableview was not focused, but some other item in screen gets focus

Could you give me the hit! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail. It becomes hard to visualise your app UI design with little information you have given.

Comment: you have this fixed